# Getting ZFS to list the physical disks in a zpool

Tags: solaris, zfs

Should be easy .... `zpool status -l rpool`  or `zpool status -v`

or so I thought .

My issue is we're running Solaris 10 on a HP DL380 G5 and I suspect the non native hardware is confusing things.
We have 2x zpools, one of which is made up of several disks.
However, when I run `zpool status -l rpool` it just lists a single disk.
We have reason to believe a disk is failing or has failed and want to remove it from the zpool but can't list the physical disks ....

What can I do?

Martin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- zpool status does not support a `-l` option, you must be confusing with something else.

  ```
  # cat /etc/release
                  Oracle Solaris 10 1/13 s10x_u11wos_24a X86
    Copyright (c) 1983, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                          Assembled 17 January 2013
  # zpool help status
  usage:
      status [-vx] [-T d|u] [pool] ... [interval [count]]
  ```
- You write you have two pools but you are running the command against the root pool which is unlikely to be the one with several disks. Just run `zpool status -v` without specifying a pool name and both of your pool should be reported with their disks.
- Should for some reason you are still missing a disk in the report, you can use `zpool history` to get an idea about what commands were used on the pools.

Comment: Ah yes sorry it's the data pool that has the failed disk.

Comment: I'm not sure it does ... I haven't access today but I'm sure the data zpool still just lists a single disk when `zpool status -v` is run..... hence the original post. Thanks for putting me straight though :) Will check tomorrow and get back to you

Comment: There was an option -l but it (kind of) changed to -P; see my answer for clarifications

Answer (score 2):

@singlespeedbeard you were not confused about the `-l` option, the original Oracle/Sun option still [mention it](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1448/gaynp.html).

Indeed, it looks like the current Ubuntu distro (22.04) zpool support that functionality but with a different switch:

`zpool status -P`

My output, notice the full path to the device:

```
  pool: bpool
 state: ONLINE
config:

    NAME                                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    bpool                                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      /dev/disk/by-partuuid/7452a4ac-8abc-aa45-9042-e790c2e92649  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
config:

    NAME                                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool                                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      /dev/disk/by-partuuid/808cd79c-2e12-aa4c-b4de-4d94fe98bc7b  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Answer (score 1):

```
zpool status -v
  pool: pve-zfs-00
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:00:00 with 0 errors on Sun Nov 13 00:24:01 2022
config:

        NAME                                                      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        pve-zfs-00                                                ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0                                                ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-MTFDDAK960TDT-1AW1ZA_02JG545D7A44710LEN_2E71DCAA  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-MTFDDAK960TDT-1AW1ZA_02JG545D7A44710LEN_2E71DCB4  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-MTFDDAK960TDT-1AW1ZA_02JG545D7A44710LEN_2E71DC59  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

ls -la /dev/disk/by-id/ata-MTFDDAK960TDT-1AW1ZA_02JG545D7A44710LEN_2E71DCAA
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec  2 11:43 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-MTFDDAK960TDT-1AW1ZA_02JG545D7A44710LEN_2E71DCAA -> ../../sdc
ls -la /dev/disk/by-id/ata-MTFDDAK960TDT-1AW1ZA_02JG545D7A44710LEN_2E71DCB4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec  2 11:43 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-MTFDDAK960TDT-1AW1ZA_02JG545D7A44710LEN_2E71DCB4 -> ../../sdd
ls -la /dev/disk/by-id/ata-MTFDDAK960TDT-1AW1ZA_02JG545D7A44710LEN_2E71DC59
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec  2 11:43 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-MTFDDAK960TDT-1AW1ZA_02JG545D7A44710LEN_2E71DC59 -> ../../sde
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).